# what is the correct inheritance/aggregation for this model

Tags: inheritance, associations, uml, aggregation

I am making a UML for a set of train cars, specifically:

Locomotive (motorized car that contains an array of all of the connected cars)
BoxCar (carries boxes/animals/cargo)
RefrigeratorCar (carries food)

I made an abstract class called RailCar that the Locomotive, BoxCar, and RefrigeratorCar all extend. So here is the problem, the Locomotive is related to the RailCar by inheritance and also possesses a has-a (aggregation) relationship with numerous RailCars.

Is this a bad design? If it is, how would you correctly represent the locomotive in a UML since it has an inheritance and aggregation relationship with the same class?

Comment: Please include your current design, that's what UML is for after all; letting everyone understand how you've designed your system. :-) And there is no thing as 'an UML'. I gues you made a class diagram?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be more realistic to model the concept of a train as a class `Train` with a one-to-many composition relationship to your `RailCar` class, stating that a train is composed of rail cars. However, your `Locomotive` is not just a plain rail car like the others, since you probably want to model facts like "a train consists of exactly one Locomotive and any number of BoxCars or RefrigeratorCars". In that case you should better keep the `Locomotive` and `RailCar` classes apart (not subsuming them under `RailCar`), such that you can express a separate one-to-one composition relationship between `Train` and `Locomotive`.

Answer (score 0):

I like having a Train class too.  But I still like the idea of a base class for all the units.  (I just wouldn't call it RailCar; perhaps "TrainUnit" or something would be more descriptive).  Locomotives and cars all have shared characteristics (brakes and connectors, for example, not to mention wheels) that can be (and should be IMHO) generalized into the base class.

This base class need not necessarily be abstract, either, if all the generalized elements work the same way for all the cars.  Even if they don't quite, you can use overriding and overloading for the subclasses when needed without going to abstracting. As a general rule, if most of the subclasses are going to use the same implementation, use overriding/overloading for the exceptions.  If most of them are going to work differently, make it abstract (no point going to the trouble of providing an implementation that nobody is going to use).

Then, the train is an aggregate of units, with the (possible) constraint that at least one must be a locomotive.  (For example, it's possible that a string of cars is sitting in a terminus, waiting for a locomotive.)